# .htaccess how to ignore directories?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following url: myweb.com/products
I have directory called "products" in my host.

when entering the above url, it redirects me to myweb.com/products/ and list the files inside the directory.
how can I ignore/disabled the way it works, so instead of searching directory with the name, it will try to find file with that name?

so when I enter myweb.com/products it will try to find file named products and if it doesnt find it will send to 403 page

*this is an example. I have more directories.

**EDIT:**
Maybe I didnt explain my self good enough.
I have the following RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*).php redirect.php [L,QSA]
```

which redirects me everything to redirect.php
since products is a folder, it doesnt redirect me to redirect.php and thats the problem..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a directory with this name, apache cannot find a file with that name.

To turn off the directory listing use the [`Options`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options) directive

```
Options -Indexes
```

This will prevent the directory contents being listed. But the error message is not a 404 page, but rather a 403 Forbidden.

Additionally, you must turn off the lookup for an [index](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex) file with

```
DirectoryIndex disabled
```

Otherwise, Apache will show an index.html, index.php, ... file, if one exists.

To prevent the slash being added to the end of directories, use

```
DirectorySlash off
```

To rewrite to a file with the same name and `.php` appended, you can use this [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule (.+)/ $1.php
```

This looks if the requested path is a directory and if it is, also checks for a regular file with the same name and `.php` as its extension. If both is true, it rewrites to the PHP file.

If you want a redirect instead of just a rewrite, you must add a `R` flag to the RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule (.+)/ $1.php [R,L]
```

And if it should rewrite to `redirect.php` instead of `product.php`, use

```
RewriteRule (.+)/ redirect.php
```

Putting all together, this gives the simplified

```
DirectorySlash off

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule .+ redirect.php [L]
```

Comment: edited my question to 403. I dont want it to be 403 error.. it should go to the products file instead. in godaddy it worked by default. now I moved to hostgator

Comment: @Ron If there is already a products directory, how should Apache find a products file? You cannot have a directory *and* a file with the same name.

Comment: the file name is ofcourse products.php.
I will tell u what I am doing. I redirect everything to page called redirect.php using rewriterule. now when trying to access myweb.com/products it should redirect me to redirect.php since thats the rewriterule, but because products is a folder/directory it doesnt do that

Comment: @Ron I modified the rule a bit. This should work now.

Comment: Ok, now it does work but still 2 issues. 1. it still redirects me to myweb.com/products/ when I want it to be without the last slash. 2. What about my rule? RewriteRule ^(.*).php redirect.php [L,QSA]

Comment: @Ron Do you want it to redirect to `redirect.php` instead of `product.php`?

Comment: Exactly. also I dont want the last slash to appear.

Comment: @Ron Ok, then try the final .htaccess.

Comment: Works perfectly! thank you ffs I tried to make it for 5 hours!

Comment: @Ron You must restart your browser, because it has cached the directory redirects from earlier tests. Or you can test with a new directory, which should not show this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Write a index.php in myweb.com/products to filter out your desired name, I guess.

Comment: what do you mean? I just put blank index.php in products but it still redirect me to myweb.com/products/. though it doesnt list the file.. but thats not what I want.